# Dynamic visualization of two histograms

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, histograms

I have two histograms `histo1` and `histo2`:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500]; 
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 500]; 
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 1.5], 500];
data4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 500];

histo1 = Histogram[{data1, data2}, {-10, 120, 0.5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 12}, {0, 100}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]

histo2 = Histogram[{data3, data4}, {-10, 120, 0.5}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 12}, {0, 100}}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

and I want them to appear alternating on the same place. With

```
ListAnimate[{histo1, histo2}]
```

they do. But I would like them to appear, depending on which button is pressed by an active observer. 
I assume, that I have to put the button generation

```
ButtonBar[{"blue" :> Print[histo1], "green" :> Print[histo2]}]
```

into a `Dynamic` or `Manipulate` surrounding. But I didn't find a proper way yet. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will easily generalize to more than two histograms:

```
Manipulate[
 Switch[whichHistogram,
  1, histo1,
  2, histo2
 ],
 {{whichHistogram, 1, "Choose histogram"}, {1 -> "blue", 2 -> "green"}}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. I did the same for a list of tables instead of histograms. They have the same labels, so is it possible to get them into one environment, where I only have to push e.g. the button "blue" and get the histogram and the table at once?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can replace `histo1` in the above with `Column[{histo1, table1}]`.

Comment: Perfect! That's the solution I needed!

Comment: I'm displaying 6 histograms, which leads to a drop-down menu instead of buttons. Any idea how to avoid this? Place would be enough for all the six buttons.

Comment: Add the option `ControlType -> SetterBar` to the `Manipulate` (see the documentation for more examples on this)

Comment: Thanks, I used it on the wrong position.

Answer (score 4):

`FlipView[{histo1, histo2}]` *flips between displaying `histo1` and `histo2` each time it is clicked.*

With some styling:

```
FlipView[Panel[##, {{Top, Center}}] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{histo1, histo2}, Style[#, 18] & /@ {"histo1", "histo2"}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider a simple implementation with a [`Toggler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Toggler.html). The only change you will need to make to your code is to explicitly set the image size of the histograms (because if the image size option is left at the default `Automatic`, the `Toggler` will shrink them down).

Reproducible data.

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 500];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 1.5], 500];
data4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 500];
```

Now the slightly modified histograms.

```
histo1 = Histogram[{data1, data2}, {-10, 120, 0.5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 12}, {0, 100}},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False];

histo2 = Histogram[{data3, data4}, {-10, 120, 0.5}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Green},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 12}, {0, 100}},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False];
```

The `Toggler` is simply

```
Toggler[Framed["Click here", RoundingRadius -> 5], {histo1, histo2}]
```

It starts out looking like this:

[image: button]

After the first click it looks like this:

[image: histo1]

After the second click it looks like this:

[image: histo2]

Any subsequent clicks causes the displayed histogram to be replaced by the other.

`Toggler` has the advantages of being simple and being its own button. The list of items to toggled can be any length, so any number items can be displayed by a `Toggler`. Shift-clicking moves backward in the list of items, which can be handy when there are a lot of items.